# Inverse Matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Let's say we have $A, B, C, D$ are all matrices.

How do we prove that $(ABCD)^{-1}$ = $D^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}.$

Sorry if the formatting is a little off.

I think this proof is supposed to use the identity matrix in some way.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3):

This follows by induction from the same fact for two factors, or by just trying out whether $D^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$ times $ABCD$ cancels (which is the case)